# Groovy 2 List convert into a Map(String,List<String>)

Tags: java, groovy

I have 2 List, details are below

```
def value =['a','b','c']
def recId =['R1','R2']
```

I need to create a single Map (string, List) with the above two lists, like

```
[R1:[a,b,c]
R2:[a,b,c]]
```

can anyone suggest me the solution?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def value =['a','b','c']
def recId =['R1','R2']

def map = recId.collectEntries{e-> [e,value] }
```

but each entry will reference the same `value` array. so, changing one of them will change all.

the following code will create a copy of `value` list for each entry

```
def map = recId.collectEntries{e-> [e,value.clone()] }
```